# JavaFX on Mac (Mojave): Textfield.copy() does not work (Java 8)

Tags: macos, javafx

I can't get Textfield.copy() to work. Samples from my code:

```
        Button btCopy = new Button("Copy");
        Button btCut = new Button("Cut");
        Button btPaste = new Button("Paste");
        Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
        TextField tf1 = new TextField("Gimme some text");
...
        btCopy.setOnAction(e -> tf1.copy());
        btClear.setOnAction(e -> tf1.clear());
        btCut.setOnAction(e -> tf1.cut());
        btPaste.setOnAction(e -> tf1.paste());
```

Clear and paste do work, but copy and cut do not - text from the TextField does not go to the clipboard.

Is this something on macOS restricting access to text in applications? If so, how could I grant access? Do I have to give permissions to the IDE I am working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (which I can reproduce on Mac OSX Catalina, JavaFX 14), is due to the fact that the `TextField` loses its selection when it loses focus, which of course happens when the user presses a button. The behavior of `cut` and `copy` are to find the selected text using the text field's `anchor` and `caretPosition` properties. When the text field loses focus, these appear to both be set to zero, meaning there is no text to copy or cut. (I'm not sure if this is considered a bug, but it certainly seems like it's not the intended behavior.)

A way to work around this is (somewhat counterintuitively) is to use a `TextFormatter` to veto any changes that are solely changes in the selection if the text field does not have focus:

```
    TextField tf1 = new TextField("Gimme some text");

    TextFormatter<String> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(change ->  {
        if (! tf1.isFocused() && ! change.isContentChange()) {
            return null ;
        }
        return change ;
    });
    tf1.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Button btCopy = new Button("Copy");
        Button btCut = new Button("Cut");
        Button btPaste = new Button("Paste");
        Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
        TextField tf1 = new TextField("Gimme some text");

        TextFormatter<String> textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(change ->  {
            if (! tf1.isFocused() && ! change.isContentChange()) {
                return null ;
            }
            return change ;
        });

        tf1.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

        btCopy.setOnAction(e -> tf1.copy());
        btClear.setOnAction(e -> tf1.clear());
        btCut.setOnAction(e -> tf1.cut());
        btPaste.setOnAction(e -> tf1.paste());

        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(btCopy, btCut, btPaste, btClear);
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tf1);
        root.setTop(toolbar);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Revision note: Initially I had a workaround that cached the anchor and caret position, and manually interacted with the system clipboard; this was extremely clunky. This solution is much more lightweight.

Comment: I suppose, in retrospect, the "losing selection on lost focus" may actually be the cause of `TextField.copy()` and `TextField.cut()` failing.

Comment: Indeed, it is the case that losing selection when the focus is lost causes `cut()` and `copy()` to fail; which allows a better solution using a `TextFormatter` to veto the selection change. Edited with this better solution.